# parse the character in string and find the specific html tag

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have string like :

```
sanitize_text = `"<b><i>this is the bold text</i></b><i>this is the italic</i>"`
```

My problem is :

1. To parse the character in string and find the specific html tag`('<b>','<i>' ...)` and then apply properties in between text .
2. Need to apply properties for each text.

I am approaching like this :

```
sanitize_arr = sanitize_text.scan(/\D\d*/)

santize_arr.each_with_index do |char, index|
  if character is new start tag == '<b>'
    Then for next characters till '</b>' I will apply some bold properties .    
  end
  if character is new start tag == '<i>'
    Then for next characters till '</i>' I will apply some italic properties .
  end
end
```

Just curious to know that I am approaching in right direction or not or is there any better solution then please let me know .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I have done it, like:

```
santize_text = "<b><u>this</u></b><i><p>this is the italic text</p></i>"

santize_arr = santize_text.scan(/\D\d*/)
char_array , html_tag_array = [], []
continue_insert_char_array, continue_insert_arr2 = false,false
santize_arr.each_with_index do |char, index|
  #To check new start tag
  continue_insert_char_array = true if char=='<' && santize_arr[index+1]!='/'
  if continue_insert_char_array
    char_array << char
    if char=='>' && continue_insert_char_array
      continue_insert_char_array = false
      html_tag_array << char_array.join
      char_array = []
    end
    next
  end

  #To check new end tag
  continue_insert_arr2 = true if char=='<' && santize_arr[index+1]=='/'
  if continue_insert_arr2
    char_array << char
    if char=='>' && continue_insert_arr2
      continue_insert_arr2 = false
      html_tag_array.delete(char_array.join.gsub('/', ""))
      char_array = []
    end
    next
  end

  # Apply the property on the character
  "Bold Char" if html_tag_array.include?("<b>")
  "Italic Char" if html_tag_array.include?("<i>")
end
```

Please let me know If there is any change to make it better .

Comment: Also looking for to do it in more better way .

Comment: How would you handle "<b> something <b> here should be </b> bold </b>" ?

Comment: Thanks to mark this point . But as I think I will get html from editor and I don't think editor will created styling like this . Please suggest any better approach to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if i'm wrong. You want to find specific html tags in text and do some manipulations with them?
Did you try [Nokogiri gem](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri.html)?

and do something like that:

```
require 'nokogiri'
nokogiri_object=Nokogiri::HTML(sanitize_text)
bold_text=nokogiri_object.css('b').text
puts bold_text
```

outputs 
    `"this is the bold text"`

Comment: Thanks for your response . Yes I had tried this :http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

Comment: but I am trying to check each character and then apply properties.

Comment: why do you need to check each character? Anyway if your problem is solved, then it's great.

Comment: Actually I am parsing the html and writing the doc , that's why need to check each character and display same text into doc as on html . I am checking just for <i>,<u>,<b> .

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own XML Parser.. no seriously! Check out [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.com/parslet/)
Infact the examples it comes with include an [XML Parser](https://github.com/kschiess/parslet/blob/master/example/simple_xml.rb)

Something like this:

```
require 'parslet'

class XML < Parslet::Parser
  root :document

  rule(:document)   { (formatting | text).repeat(1) }  
  rule(:formatting) { tag_pair('b').as(:bold) | tag_pair('u').as(:underline) | tag_pair('i').as(:italic) } 

  def tag(type)
     str('<') >> str(type) >> str('>')
  end

  def tag_pair(type)
    tag(type) >> document.maybe >> tag("/" + type)
  end

  rule(:text) {
    match('[^<>]').repeat(1).as(:text)
  }
end

 parser = XML.new
 input = ARGV[0]

 require 'parslet/convenience'
 puts parser.parse_with_debug(input).inspect
```

produces something like this...

```
> ruby xmlparser.rb "<b>bold<i>italic</i> bold again <u>underlined</u></b>"
```

[{:bold=>[{:text=>"bold"@3}, {:italic=>[{:text=>"italic"@10}]}, {:text=>" bold again "@21}, {:underline=>[{:text=>"underlined"@36}]}]}]

As you can see this tree has style nodes for bold italic etc. and the content inside them.

It could easily be extended to handle white space, and dealing with other tags you care about. It's a little harder to deal with tags you don't care about.

anyway.. just showing the possibilities.

With Parslet you typically then write a Transform class to convert this tree structure into what you are hoping to do in the end. I love the way Parslet splits parsing from using the parsed data.

Hope this helps.